# Structure for learning beatbox

Tags: learning, beatbox

I've recently started learning beatbox and know some sounds like the kick drum, the hi-hat, and the inward k-snare. I'm enjoying what I have learned so far but I feel stuck. I have a sheet of like 70 beatbox sounds and I have no idea how should I learn them. e.g. I can learn sounds but how should I put them into practice? What is a roadmap or structure to learn beatbox? I am confused about when to learn technically. How many sounds should I learn before that and etc. etc? So if there is any structure to learn beatbox even your personal one (if you want to share) then can you please share that with me. I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 3):

**Lesson One:** Listen. Observe. Practise.
There are lessons on YouTube which will start you off. These are not necessarily done by the guys best at beatbox, but by the ones willing to show you how it's done.

**Lesson Two:** Listen. Observe. Practise.
Watch & listen as the really spectacular performers do this live.
I have to say I'm not a huge fan of beatbox as a genre, but when it's done well… I defy anyone to not like this guy [put your musical prejudices aside for 3 minutes.]

**General note:** As a good proportion of the sound of beatbox comes from how it interacts with the mic, always record your performances & check the playback - like with singing, the sounds you hear in your head are not the same as the ones the mic picks up.